# CUPS & Raspbian - Printer turns on but does not print

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian, cups

I have been setting up a home print server on my raspberry pi using CUPS.

I have managed to get it to work with one of my printers, but not with an older Laser printer: Samsung ML-1520. When I print a test page, it works fine, and prints correctly, but it does not print a word document (1 page). When I send the print order, the printer spins up as if there were a job, but then it stops without printing.

I am having trouble understanding the debug info.

The following is a log form just before a print request to after a print request. --> It did spin up, but did not print anything.

This is the debug log:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ tail -f /var/log/cups/error_log
D [04/Sep/2015:21:27:16 +0000] cupsdNetIFUpdate: "lo" = localhost:631
D [04/Sep/2015:21:27:16 +0000] cupsdNetIFUpdate: "eth0" = 192.168.0.64:631
D [04/Sep/2015:21:27:16 +0000] Report: clients=9
D [04/Sep/2015:21:27:16 +0000] Report: jobs=17
D [04/Sep/2015:21:27:16 +0000] Report: jobs-active=0
D [04/Sep/2015:21:27:16 +0000] Report: printers=2
D [04/Sep/2015:21:27:16 +0000] Report: printers-implicit=0
D [04/Sep/2015:21:27:16 +0000] Report: stringpool-string-count=10340
D [04/Sep/2015:21:27:16 +0000] Report: stringpool-alloc-bytes=10360
D [04/Sep/2015:21:27:16 +0000] Report: stringpool-total-bytes=189176
D [04/Sep/2015:21:27:43 +0000] cupsdReadClient: 15 WAITING Closing on EOF
D [04/Sep/2015:21:27:43 +0000] cupsdCloseClient: 15
D [04/Sep/2015:21:27:43 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Not busy", busy="Not busy"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:27:43 +0000] cupsdReadClient: 16 WAITING Closing on EOF
D [04/Sep/2015:21:27:43 +0000] cupsdCloseClient: 16
D [04/Sep/2015:21:27:43 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Not busy", busy="Not busy"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:27:43 +0000] cupsdReadClient: 18 WAITING Closing on EOF
D [04/Sep/2015:21:27:43 +0000] cupsdCloseClient: 18
D [04/Sep/2015:21:27:43 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Not busy", busy="Not busy"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:27:43 +0000] cupsdReadClient: 19 WAITING Closing on EOF
D [04/Sep/2015:21:27:43 +0000] cupsdCloseClient: 19
D [04/Sep/2015:21:27:43 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Not busy", busy="Not busy"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:27:43 +0000] cupsdReadClient: 20 WAITING Closing on EOF
D [04/Sep/2015:21:27:43 +0000] cupsdCloseClient: 20
D [04/Sep/2015:21:27:43 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Not busy", busy="Not busy"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:27:43 +0000] cupsdReadClient: 21 WAITING Closing on EOF
D [04/Sep/2015:21:27:43 +0000] cupsdCloseClient: 21
D [04/Sep/2015:21:27:43 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Not busy", busy="Not busy"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:27:43 +0000] cupsdReadClient: 22 WAITING Closing on EOF
D [04/Sep/2015:21:27:43 +0000] cupsdCloseClient: 22
D [04/Sep/2015:21:27:43 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Not busy", busy="Not busy"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:27:43 +0000] cupsdReadClient: 23 WAITING Closing on EOF
D [04/Sep/2015:21:27:43 +0000] cupsdCloseClient: 23
D [04/Sep/2015:21:27:43 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Not busy", busy="Not busy"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:18 +0000] cupsdNetIFUpdate: "lo" = localhost:631
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:18 +0000] cupsdNetIFUpdate: "eth0" = 192.168.0.64:631
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:18 +0000] Report: clients=1
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:18 +0000] Report: jobs=17
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:18 +0000] Report: jobs-active=0
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:18 +0000] Report: printers=2
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:18 +0000] Report: printers-implicit=0
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:18 +0000] Report: stringpool-string-count=10340
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:18 +0000] Report: stringpool-alloc-bytes=10360
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:18 +0000] Report: stringpool-total-bytes=189176
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:31 +0000] cupsdAcceptClient: 15 from 192.168.0.100:631 (IPv4)
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:31 +0000] cupsdReadClient: 15 POST /printers/Samsung_ML-1520 HTTP/1.1
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:31 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Active clients", busy="Not busy"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:31 +0000] cupsdAuthorize: No authentication data provided.
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:31 +0000] cupsdReadClient: 15 1.0 Get-Printer-Attributes 11
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:31 +0000] Get-Printer-Attributes http://192.168.0.64:631/printers/Samsung_ML-1520
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:31 +0000] Returning IPP successful-ok for Get-Printer-Attributes (http://192.168.0.64:631/printers/Samsung_ML-1520) from 192.168.0.100
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:31 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Not busy", busy="Active clients"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:32 +0000] cupsdAcceptClient: 16 from 192.168.0.100:631 (IPv4)
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:32 +0000] cupsdReadClient: 16 POST /printers/Samsung_ML-1520 HTTP/1.1
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:32 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Active clients", busy="Not busy"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:32 +0000] cupsdAuthorize: No authentication data provided.
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:32 +0000] cupsdReadClient: 16 1.0 Get-Printer-Attributes 11
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:32 +0000] Get-Printer-Attributes http://192.168.0.64:631/printers/Samsung_ML-1520
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:32 +0000] Returning IPP successful-ok for Get-Printer-Attributes (http://192.168.0.64:631/printers/Samsung_ML-1520) from 192.168.0.100
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:32 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Not busy", busy="Active clients"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:32 +0000] cupsdAcceptClient: 18 from 192.168.0.100:631 (IPv4)
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:32 +0000] cupsdReadClient: 18 POST /printers/Samsung_ML-1520 HTTP/1.1
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:32 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Active clients", busy="Not busy"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:32 +0000] cupsdAuthorize: No authentication data provided.
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:32 +0000] cupsdReadClient: 18 1.0 Get-Printer-Attributes 11
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:32 +0000] Get-Printer-Attributes http://192.168.0.64:631/printers/Samsung_ML-1520
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:32 +0000] Returning IPP successful-ok for Get-Printer-Attributes (http://192.168.0.64:631/printers/Samsung_ML-1520) from 192.168.0.100
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:32 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Not busy", busy="Active clients"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] cupsdAcceptClient: 19 from 192.168.0.100:631 (IPv4)
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] cupsdReadClient: 19 POST /printers/Samsung_ML-1520 HTTP/1.1
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Active clients", busy="Not busy"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] cupsdAuthorize: No authentication data provided.
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] cupsdReadClient: 19 1.0 Get-Jobs 10
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] Get-Jobs http://192.168.0.64:631/printers/Samsung_ML-1520
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] Returning IPP successful-ok for Get-Jobs (http://192.168.0.64:631/printers/Samsung_ML-1520) from 192.168.0.100
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Not busy", busy="Active clients"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] cupsdAcceptClient: 20 from 192.168.0.100:631 (IPv4)
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] cupsdReadClient: 20 POST /printers/HP_Color_LaserJet_CP1215 HTTP/1.1
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Active clients", busy="Not busy"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] cupsdAuthorize: No authentication data provided.
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] cupsdReadClient: 20 1.0 Get-Printer-Attributes 11
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] Get-Printer-Attributes http://192.168.0.64:631/printers/HP_Color_LaserJet_CP1215
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] Returning IPP successful-ok for Get-Printer-Attributes (http://192.168.0.64:631/printers/HP_Color_LaserJet_CP1215) from 192.168.0.100
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Not busy", busy="Active clients"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] cupsdAcceptClient: 21 from 192.168.0.100:631 (IPv4)
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] cupsdReadClient: 21 POST /printers/HP_Color_LaserJet_CP1215 HTTP/1.1
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Active clients", busy="Not busy"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] cupsdAuthorize: No authentication data provided.
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] cupsdReadClient: 21 1.0 Get-Jobs 10
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] Get-Jobs http://192.168.0.64:631/printers/HP_Color_LaserJet_CP1215
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] Returning IPP successful-ok for Get-Jobs (http://192.168.0.64:631/printers/HP_Color_LaserJet_CP1215) from 192.168.0.100
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Not busy", busy="Active clients"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] cupsdAcceptClient: 22 from 192.168.0.100:631 (IPv4)
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] cupsdReadClient: 22 POST /printers/Samsung_ML-1520 HTTP/1.1
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Active clients", busy="Not busy"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] cupsdAuthorize: No authentication data provided.
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] cupsdReadClient: 22 1.0 Get-Printer-Attributes 11
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] Get-Printer-Attributes http://192.168.0.64:631/printers/Samsung_ML-1520
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] Returning IPP successful-ok for Get-Printer-Attributes (http://192.168.0.64:631/printers/Samsung_ML-1520) from 192.168.0.100
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Not busy", busy="Active clients"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] cupsdAcceptClient: 23 from 192.168.0.100:631 (IPv4)
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] cupsdReadClient: 23 POST /printers/Samsung_ML-1520 HTTP/1.1
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Active clients", busy="Not busy"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] cupsdAuthorize: No authentication data provided.
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] cupsdReadClient: 23 1.0 Print-Job 2
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] Print-Job http://192.168.0.64:631/printers/Samsung_ML-1520
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] [Job ???] Auto-typing file...
I [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] [Job ???] Request file type is application/vnd.cups-raw.
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] cupsdMarkDirty(----J-)
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Active clients and dirty files", busy="Active clients"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] add_job: requesting-user-name="Sandu Rajapakse"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] Adding default job-sheets values "none,none"...
I [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] [Job 18] Adding start banner page "none".
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] Discarding unused job-created event...
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] cupsdMarkDirty(----J-)
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Active clients and dirty files", busy="Active clients and dirty files"
I [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] [Job 18] Adding end banner page "none".
I [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] [Job 18] File of type application/vnd.cups-raw queued by "Sandu Rajapakse".
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] [Job 18] hold_until=0
I [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] [Job 18] Queued on "Samsung_ML-1520" by "Sandu Rajapakse".
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] cupsdMarkDirty(----J-)
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Active clients and dirty files", busy="Active clients and dirty files"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Active clients and dirty files", busy="Active clients and dirty files"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] Discarding unused printer-state-changed event...
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] [Job 18] job-sheets=none,none
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] [Job 18] argv[0]="Samsung_ML-1520"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] [Job 18] argv[1]="18"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] [Job 18] argv[2]="Sandu Rajapakse"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] [Job 18] argv[3]="Microsoft Word - Mob Spawning.docx"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] [Job 18] argv[4]="1"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] [Job 18] argv[5]="job-uuid=urn:uuid:e9ae1e81-f7e9-38d2-7bfe-2894fa263899 job-originating-host-name=192.168.0.100 time-at-creation=1441402113 time-at-processing=1441402113"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] [Job 18] argv[6]="/var/spool/cups/d00018-001"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] [Job 18] envp[0]="CUPS_CACHEDIR=/var/cache/cups"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] [Job 18] envp[1]="CUPS_DATADIR=/usr/share/cups"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] [Job 18] envp[2]="CUPS_DOCROOT=/usr/share/cups/doc-root"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] [Job 18] envp[3]="CUPS_FONTPATH=/usr/share/cups/fonts"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] [Job 18] envp[4]="CUPS_REQUESTROOT=/var/spool/cups"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] [Job 18] envp[5]="CUPS_SERVERBIN=/usr/lib/cups"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] [Job 18] envp[6]="CUPS_SERVERROOT=/etc/cups"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] [Job 18] envp[7]="CUPS_STATEDIR=/var/run/cups"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] [Job 18] envp[8]="HOME=/var/spool/cups/tmp"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] [Job 18] envp[9]="PATH=/usr/lib/cups/filter:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] [Job 18] envp[10]="SERVER_ADMIN=root@raspberrypi"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] [Job 18] envp[11]="SOFTWARE=CUPS/1.5.3"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] [Job 18] envp[12]="TMPDIR=/var/spool/cups/tmp"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] [Job 18] envp[13]="TZ=Etc/UTC"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] [Job 18] envp[14]="USER=root"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] [Job 18] envp[15]="CUPS_SERVER=/var/run/cups/cups.sock"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] [Job 18] envp[16]="CUPS_ENCRYPTION=IfRequested"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] [Job 18] envp[17]="IPP_PORT=631"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] [Job 18] envp[18]="CHARSET=utf-8"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] [Job 18] envp[19]="LANG=en_US.UTF-8"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] [Job 18] envp[20]="PPD=/etc/cups/ppd/Samsung_ML-1520.ppd"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] [Job 18] envp[21]="RIP_MAX_CACHE=128m"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] [Job 18] envp[22]="CONTENT_TYPE=application/vnd.cups-raw"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] [Job 18] envp[23]="DEVICE_URI=usb://Samsung/ML-1520?serial=2X61BKAXC08883T."
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] [Job 18] envp[24]="PRINTER_INFO=Samsung ML-1520"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] [Job 18] envp[25]="PRINTER_LOCATION=Sandu's Room - Near PC"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] [Job 18] envp[26]="PRINTER=Samsung_ML-1520"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] [Job 18] envp[27]="PRINTER_STATE_REASONS=none"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] [Job 18] envp[28]="CUPS_FILETYPE=document"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] [Job 18] envp[29]="AUTH_I****"
I [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] [Job 18] Started backend /usr/lib/cups/backend/usb (PID 2413)
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] Discarding unused job-state-changed event...
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] Returning IPP successful-ok for Print-Job (http://192.168.0.64:631/printers/Samsung_ML-1520) from 192.168.0.100
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Printing jobs and dirty files", busy="Active clients and dirty files"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] [Job 18] Printing on printer with URI: usb://Samsung/ML-1520?serial=2X61BKAXC08883T.
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] [Job 18] libusb_get_device_list=5
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] [Job 18] STATE: +connecting-to-device
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] Discarding unused printer-state-changed event...
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] [Job 18] STATE: -connecting-to-device
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] Discarding unused printer-state-changed event...
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] [Job 18] STATE: +connecting-to-device
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] Discarding unused printer-state-changed event...
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] [Job 18] STATE: -connecting-to-device
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] Discarding unused printer-state-changed event...
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] [Job 18] Device protocol: 2
I [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] [Job 18] Sending data to printer.
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] [Job 18] Set job-printer-state-message to "Sending data to printer.", current level=INFO
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] Discarding unused job-progress event...
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] Discarding unused printer-state-changed event...
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] [Job 18] PAGE: 1 1
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] Discarding unused job-progress event...
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] [Job 18] Read 8192 bytes of print data...
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] [Job 18] Wrote 8192 bytes of print data...
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] [Job 18] Sending print file, 8192 bytes...
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] [Job 18] Read 8192 bytes of print data...
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] [Job 18] Wrote 8192 bytes of print data...
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] [Job 18] Sending print file, 16384 bytes...
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] [Job 18] Read 8192 bytes of print data...
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] [Job 18] Wrote 8192 bytes of print data...
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] [Job 18] Sending print file, 24576 bytes...
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] [Job 18] Read 8192 bytes of print data...
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] [Job 18] Wrote 8192 bytes of print data...
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] [Job 18] Sending print file, 32768 bytes...
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] [Job 18] Read 8192 bytes of print data...
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] [Job 18] Wrote 8192 bytes of print data...
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] [Job 18] Sending print file, 40960 bytes...
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] [Job 18] Read 779 bytes of print data...
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] [Job 18] Wrote 779 bytes of print data...
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] [Job 18] Sending print file, 41739 bytes...
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] [Job 18] Sent 41739 bytes...
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:33 +0000] [Job 18] Waiting for read thread to exit...
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:40 +0000] [Job 18] Read thread still active, aborting the pending read...
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:42 +0000] [Job 18] Resetting printer.
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:42 +0000] PID 2413 (/usr/lib/cups/backend/usb) exited with no errors.
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:42 +0000] Discarding unused job-completed event...
I [04/Sep/2015:21:28:42 +0000] [Job 18] Job completed.
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:42 +0000] cupsdMarkDirty(----J-)
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:42 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Printing jobs and dirty files", busy="Printing jobs and dirty files"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:42 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Printing jobs and dirty files", busy="Printing jobs and dirty files"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:42 +0000] Discarding unused printer-state-changed event...
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:43 +0000] [Job 18] Unloading...
I [04/Sep/2015:21:29:04 +0000] Saving job.cache...
D [04/Sep/2015:21:29:04 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Not busy", busy="Printing jobs and dirty files"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:29:20 +0000] cupsdNetIFUpdate: "lo" = localhost:631
D [04/Sep/2015:21:29:20 +0000] cupsdNetIFUpdate: "eth0" = 192.168.0.64:631
D [04/Sep/2015:21:29:20 +0000] Report: clients=9
D [04/Sep/2015:21:29:20 +0000] Report: jobs=18
D [04/Sep/2015:21:29:20 +0000] Report: jobs-active=0
D [04/Sep/2015:21:29:20 +0000] Report: printers=2
D [04/Sep/2015:21:29:20 +0000] Report: printers-implicit=0
D [04/Sep/2015:21:29:20 +0000] Report: stringpool-string-count=10342
D [04/Sep/2015:21:29:20 +0000] Report: stringpool-alloc-bytes=10360
D [04/Sep/2015:21:29:20 +0000] Report: stringpool-total-bytes=189208
D [04/Sep/2015:21:29:33 +0000] cupsdReadClient: 15 WAITING Closing on EOF
D [04/Sep/2015:21:29:33 +0000] cupsdCloseClient: 15
D [04/Sep/2015:21:29:33 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Not busy", busy="Not busy"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:29:33 +0000] cupsdReadClient: 16 WAITING Closing on EOF
D [04/Sep/2015:21:29:33 +0000] cupsdCloseClient: 16
D [04/Sep/2015:21:29:33 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Not busy", busy="Not busy"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:29:33 +0000] cupsdReadClient: 18 WAITING Closing on EOF
D [04/Sep/2015:21:29:33 +0000] cupsdCloseClient: 18
D [04/Sep/2015:21:29:33 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Not busy", busy="Not busy"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:29:33 +0000] cupsdReadClient: 19 WAITING Closing on EOF
D [04/Sep/2015:21:29:33 +0000] cupsdCloseClient: 19
D [04/Sep/2015:21:29:33 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Not busy", busy="Not busy"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:29:33 +0000] cupsdReadClient: 20 WAITING Closing on EOF
D [04/Sep/2015:21:29:33 +0000] cupsdCloseClient: 20
D [04/Sep/2015:21:29:33 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Not busy", busy="Not busy"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:29:33 +0000] cupsdReadClient: 21 WAITING Closing on EOF
D [04/Sep/2015:21:29:33 +0000] cupsdCloseClient: 21
D [04/Sep/2015:21:29:33 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Not busy", busy="Not busy"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:29:33 +0000] cupsdReadClient: 22 WAITING Closing on EOF
D [04/Sep/2015:21:29:33 +0000] cupsdCloseClient: 22
D [04/Sep/2015:21:29:33 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Not busy", busy="Not busy"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:29:33 +0000] cupsdReadClient: 23 WAITING Closing on EOF
D [04/Sep/2015:21:29:33 +0000] cupsdCloseClient: 23
D [04/Sep/2015:21:29:33 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Not busy", busy="Not busy"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:27:16 +0000] cupsdNetIFUpdate: "lo" = localhost:631
D [04/Sep/2015:21:27:16 +0000] cupsdNetIFUpdate: "eth0" = 192.168.0.64:631
D [04/Sep/2015:21:27:16 +0000] Report: clients=9
D [04/Sep/2015:21:27:16 +0000] Report: jobs=17
D [04/Sep/2015:21:27:16 +0000] Report: jobs-active=0
D [04/Sep/2015:21:27:16 +0000] Report: printers=2
D [04/Sep/2015:21:27:16 +0000] Report: printers-implicit=0
D [04/Sep/2015:21:27:16 +0000] Report: stringpool-string-count=10340
D [04/Sep/2015:21:27:16 +0000] Report: stringpool-alloc-bytes=10360
D [04/Sep/2015:21:27:16 +0000] Report: stringpool-total-bytes=189176
D [04/Sep/2015:21:27:43 +0000] cupsdReadClient: 15 WAITING Closing on EOF
D [04/Sep/2015:21:27:43 +0000] cupsdCloseClient: 15
D [04/Sep/2015:21:27:43 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Not busy", busy="Not busy"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:27:43 +0000] cupsdReadClient: 16 WAITING Closing on EOF
D [04/Sep/2015:21:27:43 +0000] cupsdCloseClient: 16
D [04/Sep/2015:21:27:43 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Not busy", busy="Not busy"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:27:43 +0000] cupsdReadClient: 18 WAITING Closing on EOF
D [04/Sep/2015:21:27:43 +0000] cupsdCloseClient: 18
D [04/Sep/2015:21:27:43 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Not busy", busy="Not busy"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:27:43 +0000] cupsdReadClient: 19 WAITING Closing on EOF
D [04/Sep/2015:21:27:43 +0000] cupsdCloseClient: 19
D [04/Sep/2015:21:27:43 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Not busy", busy="Not busy"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:27:43 +0000] cupsdReadClient: 20 WAITING Closing on EOF
D [04/Sep/2015:21:27:43 +0000] cupsdCloseClient: 20
D [04/Sep/2015:21:27:43 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Not busy", busy="Not busy"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:27:43 +0000] cupsdReadClient: 21 WAITING Closing on EOF
D [04/Sep/2015:21:27:43 +0000] cupsdCloseClient: 21
D [04/Sep/2015:21:27:43 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Not busy", busy="Not busy"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:27:43 +0000] cupsdReadClient: 22 WAITING Closing on EOF
D [04/Sep/2015:21:27:43 +0000] cupsdCloseClient: 22
D [04/Sep/2015:21:27:43 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Not busy", busy="Not busy"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:27:43 +0000] cupsdReadClient: 23 WAITING Closing on EOF
D [04/Sep/2015:21:27:43 +0000] cupsdCloseClient: 23
D [04/Sep/2015:21:27:43 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Not busy", busy="Not busy"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:18 +0000] cupsdNetIFUpdate: "lo" = localhost:631
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:18 +0000] cupsdNetIFUpdate: "eth0" = 192.168.0.64:631
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:18 +0000] Report: clients=1
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:18 +0000] Report: jobs=17
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:18 +0000] Report: jobs-active=0
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:18 +0000] Report: printers=2
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:18 +0000] Report: printers-implicit=0
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:18 +0000] Report: stringpool-string-count=10340
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:18 +0000] Report: stringpool-alloc-bytes=10360
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:18 +0000] Report: stringpool-total-bytes=189176
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:31 +0000] cupsdAcceptClient: 15 from 192.168.0.100:631 (IPv4)
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:31 +0000] cupsdReadClient: 15 POST /printers/Samsung_ML-1520 HTTP/1.1
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:31 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Active clients", busy="Not busy"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:31 +0000] cupsdAuthorize: No authentication data provided.
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:31 +0000] cupsdReadClient: 15 1.0 Get-Printer-Attributes 11
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:31 +0000] Get-Printer-Attributes http://192.168.0.64:631/printers/Samsung_ML-1520
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:31 +0000] Returning IPP successful-ok for Get-Printer-Attributes (http://192.168.0.64:631/printers/Samsung_ML-1520) from 192.168.0.100
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:31 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Not busy", busy="Active clients"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:32 +0000] cupsdAcceptClient: 16 from 192.168.0.100:631 (IPv4)
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:32 +0000] cupsdReadClient: 16 POST /printers/Samsung_ML-1520 HTTP/1.1
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:32 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Active clients", busy="Not busy"
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:32 +0000] cupsdAuthorize: No authentication data provided.
D [04/Sep/2015:21:28:32 +0000] cupsdReadClient: 16 1.0 Ge
```

**Solution:**
I just figured out what was wrong. So, as I mentioned in my original post, the printer was able to print the test page from CUPS which meant that that connection and communication was pretty good between the Printer and CUPS. But when I send a page to print from the PC, it fails. @thrig looked at the debug info and told me that it was sending the whole file. This lead me to think this was a driver issue.

Since this printer is an old Samsung printer, it uses the Samsun Vniversal print driver. I figured this was causing a miscommunication between the PC and CUPS (which had a printer specific driver). So I went to the Samsung ML-1520 website and looked for device specific driver. I found one that was a GDI print driver. Remembering that the driver used in CUPS also mentioned GDI I knew this was the solution.

However, it is an older driver made for Windows 7 and I am using Windows 10 and I got a unsigned driver error from windows which prevented me from installing it.

With this information, I went looking for a signed version of a GDI driver. I found the GDI driver for the newer ML-2250. I also came to learn that it was compatible with my printer as well. I downloaded that and ran the extraction. After it was extracted, I went into the files and found the x64 GDI driver within. I then reinstalled the ML-1520 printer on my PC, but when it asked to select the driver, I selected 'Have Disk' and selected the Signed GDI driver (rather than picking from the list). After it installed, I ran a print and it Worked! I also tested with word documents, PDFs and Images to be sure but it seems to have fixed the problem.

**tl;dr: It was a driver issue. Do not use the universal print driver. Get a GDI driver from the Samsung website (maybe from a newer version, if your printer is old). It must be signed. Install printer on PC and use the GDI driver instead of selecting from disk.**

Comment: That looks like you sent a raw `*.docx` at the printer, which may indeed cause the printer to fail. Can you try printing a PDF or PostScript file?

Comment: @thrig - I just saved the word doc as a pdf and printed the pdf and still nothing. It spins up and then nothing... any ideas why that may be?

Comment: Odd, I wonder what the test page is doing differently. Can you get a debug log while that is done, to maybe see what format it is sending, or processes (filters) it is calling?

Comment: @thrig - Here it is: http://pastebin.com/BL4kBJP1 (this was with the printer on standby, then i ran the tail and then sent the pdf file to the printer. It started running and turned off without any printing.

Comment: @thrig - Thank You for your help, I just solved the problem. After you said it was just sending the file I thought it may be an interpretation (driver) problem which lead me to the solution. I will add the solution so it will help people in the future. This stumped me for a good day.